# How to make a combination of radio and checkbox?

Tags: javascript, forms, input

I have HTML form, where I use "radio" buttons, but I would like them to work as if they were a combination of radio and checkbox: one option is possible to be checked but also there is a possibilty to unselect an option.

Any ideas?

Comment: You might rather want to check in with the people at http://ux.stackexchange.com.

Comment: this may help you http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/81946/checkboxes-or-radio-buttons-only-one-or-zero-choices

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly what you asked for but a work around.

You could just have an extra radio button which is entitled something like "none of the above".
With this radio button selected as default, using `checked` as below.

`<input type="radio" checked="checked" />`

That way, instead of unselecting your choice, you reselect the initial radio button.